# How to paginate or organize Expression Engine by custom field data input

Tags: pagination, customization, expressionengine

I have an ExpressionEngine site that takes information entered from an admin, and information entered from users through SafeCracker, and displays that information in a timeline format.

The information that is entered has a custom field called {story_year}. We use that field to sort the entries based on the entered date. This means that users can specify a date, as well as admins.

Because showing hundreds of entries at once takes a long time load, we've introduced pagination. But that pagination breaks it up arbitrarily by amount.

Is there a way to paginate by {story_year}? Possibly conditionals like:

```
{if story_year >= "2010" }
  {page}
    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="{if current_page}active{/if}">&bull;</a></li>
  {/page}
{if:elseif story_year >= "2000"}
  {page}
    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="{if current_page}active{/if}">&bull;</a></li>
  {/page}
{/if}
```

Relevant URLs are here:
http://thinkx.net/clients/manship/index.php/timeline - the ultimate display of the timeline.
http://thinkx.net/clients/manship/index.php/Timeline/add - the field entries we sort by.

Comment: You might want to post this to the ExpressionEngine specific StackExchange site for a faster response: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought I was not allowed there yet.

Comment: Absolutely, the site has been in public beta for 3 months now. Post away.